# Excel to Text Conversion Inside of MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab, text

I can convert the excel file to text manually inside of Excel.

However to make my MATLAB scripts more autonomous and not relying on

another application, I am struggling with converting a .xlsx file to

text inside of MATLAB. Is there a function or routine to convert a

.xlsx file to .txt?

Answer (score 0):

`xlsxread()` and `csvwrite()` should do the trick.

Otherwise if for some reason you don't want a csv, you could use `fprintf()`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html but CSV is plain text so I doubt this is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
[~, ~, rawData] Data = xlsread('yourfile');
save('text.txt', 'rawData', '-ASCII');
```